# I want toast message to be displayed when alarm rings for android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

My question is, I want toast message to be displayed when alarm is set to rings for android..I have AnCal alarm application ..I have tried a lot but its not working ...I need your help...

Thanks and regard
Sarfaraz

Comment: the code is very big...to display on this screen

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example that will set alarm every 30 seconds and when the alarm will ring the toast will appear and when alarm will be set notification will be pushed. If I misunderstood your question post comment so i can delete this answer to avoid UN-necessary post.

Step 1 MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.alarmmanager;

import com.example.alarmmanager.NotificationReceiverActivity;
import com.example.alarmmanager.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver alarm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    alarm = new AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
}

    public void startRepeatingTimer(View view) {
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
     alarm.SetAlarm(context);
     }else{
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }

    public void cancelRepeatingTimer(View view){
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
     alarm.CancelAlarm(context);
     }else{
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }

    public void onetimeTimer(View view){
     Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
     if(alarm != null){
     alarm.setOnetimeTimer(context);
     createNotification(view);
     }else{
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }
    public void createNotification(View view) {
      /*********** Create notification ***********/

            final NotificationManager mgr=
                (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                                                            "Android Example Status message!",
                                                            System.currentTimeMillis());

            // This pending intent will open after notification click
            PendingIntent i= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                    new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class),
                                                    0);

            note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Android Example Notification Title",
                                    "This is the android example notification message", i);

            //After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
            //note.number=2;
            mgr.notify(0, note);

        }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Step 2 AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.example.alarmmanager;

import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;  

public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    //You can do the processing here update the widget/remote views.
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

    if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
    msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
    }
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

    Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}
public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 30 seconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pi);
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
 AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);

}
```

}

Step 3 NotificationReceiverActivity.java

```
package com.example.alarmmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NotificationReceiverActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
}
}
```

Step 4 NotificationService.java // this is to push notification you can remove this if you do not want notifications

```
package com.example.alarmmanager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
public class NotificationService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
   super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    final NotificationManager mgr=
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                                                        "Android Example Status message!",
                                                        System.currentTimeMillis());

        // This pending intent will open after notification click
        PendingIntent i= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class),
                                                0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Android Example Notification Title",
                                "This is the android example notification message", i);

        //After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
        note.number=startId;
        mgr.notify(0, note);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Step 5 : AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'/>

 <receiver android:name="com.example.alarmmanager.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver">  </receiver>
     <service android:name="com.example.alarmmanager.NotificationService"
             android:enabled="true" />
```

Step 6 activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:onClick="startRepeatingTimer"
    android:text="Start Alarm repeating 30 sec" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="cancelRepeatingTimer"
    android:text="Cancel Alarm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:onClick="onetimeTimer"
    android:text="Start One Time Alarm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 7 result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView android:text="This is the result activity opened from the notification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 8 Run project